# How can I speed up random init?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, random, yocto

I have an embedded device running a linux environment built with Yocto.  I have both openssh-server and nginx running, both of which take 1 minute to start because they are waiting on enough entropy:

From dmesg: `56.338824] random: crng init done`

uname: `Linux beaglebone 5.0.12-jumpnow #1 Wed Sep 25 22:09:50 UTC 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux`

Is there any way I can speed up this process?  Perhaps cache some entropy between reboots?  There is no mouse or keyboard, and may be very little to no network traffic for faster entropy generation.

Comment: You may have a hardware RNG on that board, in which case: https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/3530/entropy-depletion-in-dev-random-on-beaglebone That'd be preferred over (or in addition to) haveged.

Answer (score 3):

There is a package called haveged that serves just this purpose.